# SOAP webservice header error

Tags: ios, web-services, soap

I am first time using soap service,

This is the data server expecting,

```
POST /updateLocation.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.geoming.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <setLocation xmlns="http://geoming.com/">
      <pLati>string</pLati>
      <pLongi>string</pLongi>
      <pStatusMsg>string</pStatusMsg>
      <pID>string</pID>
      <pSpeed>string</pSpeed>
      <pStreet1>string</pStreet1>
      <pStreet2>string</pStreet2>
      <pCity>string</pCity>
      <pState>string</pState>
      <pCountry>string</pCountry>
      <pDate>string</pDate>
      <pTimeZone>string</pTimeZone>
    </setLocation>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

and in objective c section i am doing like this,

```
soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                       "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/\">"
                       "<soap12:Body>"
                       "<setLocation xmlns=\"http://www.geoming.com/\">"
                       "<pLati>-33.868</pLati>"
                       "<pLongi>151.2086</pLongi>"
                       "<pStatusMsg>santanu test</pStatusMsg>"
                       "<pID>3</pID>"
                       "<pSpeed>12</pSpeed>"
                       "<pStreet1>CD - 96</pStreet1>"
                       "<pStreet2>Salt lake city</pStreet2>"
                       "<pCity>kolkata</pCity>"
                       "<pState>west bengal</pState>"
                       "<pCountry>india</pCountry>"
                       "<pDate>16-04-2015</pDate>"
                       "<pTimeZone>-5.30</pTimeZone>"
                       "</setLocation>"
                       "</soap12:Body>"
                       "</soap12:Envelope>"];

        //Now create a request to the URL

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.geoming.com/updateLocation.asmx"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

        //ad required headers to the request

        [theRequest addValue:@"www.geoming.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
        [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [theRequest addValue: @"http://www.geoming.com/setLocation" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

It's always showing "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://www.geoming.com/setLocation. System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()".

Unable to to find the solution as i am new in ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong SOAPAction. Instead  @"http://www.geoming.com/setLocation" you need use @"http://geoming.com/setLocation"

Try my code:

```
static NSString* const cstrSetLocMsg = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                                                    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                                                    "<soap:Body>"
                                                    "<setLocation xmlns=\"http://geoming.com/\">"
                                                    "<pLati>-33.868</pLati>"
                                                    "<pLongi>151.2086</pLongi>"
                                                    "<pStatusMsg>santanu test</pStatusMsg>"
                                                    "<pID>3</pID>"
                                                    "<pSpeed>12</pSpeed>"
                                                    "<pStreet1>CD - 96</pStreet1>"
                                                    "<pStreet2>Salt lake city</pStreet2>"
                                                    "<pCity>kolkata</pCity>"
                                                    "<pState>west bengal</pState>"
                                                    "<pCountry>india</pCountry>"
                                                    "<pDate>16-04-2015</pDate>"
                                                    "<pTimeZone>-5.30</pTimeZone>"
                                                    "</setLocation>"
                                                    "</soap:Body>"
                                                    "</soap:Envelope>";
```

And create request:

```
+ (NSMutableURLRequest*) requestSetLoc{
NSString *_soapMsg = cstrSetLocMsg;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.geoming.com/updateLocation.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]  initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.f] autorelease];
NSString *msgLength =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [_soapMsg length]];
[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"http://geoming.com/setLocation"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[req addValue:msgLength  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody: [_soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
return req;}
```

It should works!

Comment: Hi, Thanks .. it's showing an error in return. Can u help on it , error is "string or binary data would be truncated "

Comment: I think some fields  have restrictions on the server.  For example, if the some field is a varchar(10), and you try to put 20 characters in to it, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your string to

```
soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
                       <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/\">\
                       <soap12:Body>\
                       <setLocation xmlns=\"http://www.geoming.com/\">\
                       <pLati>-33.868</pLati>\
                       <pLongi>151.2086</pLongi>\
                       <pStatusMsg>santanu test</pStatusMsg>\
                       <pID>3</pID>\
                       <pSpeed>12</pSpeed>\
                       <pStreet1>CD - 96</pStreet1>\
                       <pStreet2>Salt lake city</pStreet2>
                       <pCity>kolkata</pCity>\
                       <pState>west bengal</pState>\
                       <pCountry>india</pCountry>\
                       <pDate>16-04-2015</pDate>\
                       <pTimeZone>-5.30</pTimeZone>\
                       </setLocation>
                       </soap12:Body>\
                       </soap12:Envelope>"];
```

Comment: still showing the err " System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://www.geoming.com/setLocation."

Comment: the url is "http://www.geoming.com/updateLocation.asmx?op=setLocation" , where i am wrong..??